# Error using bsxfun Mixed integer class inputs are not supported

Tags: matlab, image-processing, neural-network

I'm working on a project on neural network and my working medium is Matlab. While running the following code:

```
net=train(net, feat_mat, gt_mat);
```

The neural network that I've used is a ffnn with 3 hidden layer. The highest value in feat_mat is 255 and the lowest is 0. The highest value in gt_mat is 1 and the lowest is 0. feat_mat has 5x423500 uint8 value and gt_mat has 1x423500 uint8.

I got the following error:

> Error using bsxfun
> Mixed integer class inputs are not supported.
>
> Error in mapminmax.apply (line 6)
>
> Error in nnet.mode.matlab.processInput (line 7)
>
> Error in nnet.mode.matlab.processInputs (line 12)
>
> Error in nncalc.preCalcData (line 16)
>
> Error in nncalc.setup1>setupImpl (line 176)
>
> Error in nncalc.setup1 (line 16)
>
> Error in nncalc.setup (line 7)
>
> Error in network/train (line 357)

I don't understand why this error is occuring. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

P.S: I've searched google and other questions at this site but none of them are relevant to mine.

Comment: Just convert them to `double()` when passing into `train` (i.e. not a "mixed integer class")?

Comment: @Wolife It worked!! Thanks a ton. You don't know how much time I've wasted behind this and now voila!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As detailed in the error, `train` relies on `bsxfun`, which doesn't support mixed integer classes.

Your inputs are `uint8` arrays, i.e. mixed integers, so `train` falls over.

To get around this, simply convert the inputs to doubles

```
net = train( net, double(feat_mat), double(gt_mat) );
```